# How do I extract metadata from a var when a function returns its symbol?

Tags: clojurescript, clojure.spec, re-frame

I'm using [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/) with [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) to validate `app-db`, much like in the [todomvc](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/tree/master/examples/todomvc/) example.

When a user makes an invalid entry, I'm using `s/explain-data` (in a re-frame interceptor) to return a `problems` map naming the `:pred`icate which caused validation failure. This predicate is a symbol like `project.db/validation-function`.

My validation function has metadata which is accessible from the repl using:

```clj
(meta #'project.db/validation-function)
```

The function definition (in the `project.db` namespace) looks like this:

```clj
(defn validation-function
  "docstring..."
  {:error-message "error message"}
  [param]
  (function-body...)
```

The problem is I can't work out how to retrieve the metadata dynamically (working in `project.events` namespace), for example:

```clj
(let [explain-data (s/explain-data spec db)
      pred (->> (:cljs.spec.alpha/problems explain-data) first :pred)
      msg (what-goes-here? pred)]
  msg)
```

I've tried the following things in place of `what-goes-here?`:

- `symbol?` gives `true`
- `str` gives `"project.db/validation-function"`
- `meta` gives `nil`
- `var` gives a compile-time error "Unable to resolve var: p1__46744# in this context"

I think the problem is that I'm getting a symbol, but I need the var it refers to, which is where the metadata lives.

I've tried using a macro, but don't really know what I'm doing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171851/780743) is the closest discussion I could find, but I couldn't work it out.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't do this because vars are not reified in ClojureScript.

From https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_special_forms :

> - var notes
>
>   - Vars are not reified at runtime. When the compiler encounters the var special form it emits a Var instance reflecting **compile time** metadata. (This satisfies many common **static** use cases.)

At the REPL, when you evaluate

```
(meta #'project.db/validation-function)
```

this is the same as

```
(meta (var project.db/validation-function))
```

and when `(var project.db/validation-function)` is compiled, JavaScript code is emitted to create a `cljs.core/Var` instance that contains, among other things, the data that you can obtain using `meta`. If you are curious, the relevant [analyzer](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/132d3aa232921a3cea66f830d61c89be78c581cb/src/main/clojure/cljs/analyzer.cljc#L1317-L1360) and [compiler](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/132d3aa232921a3cea66f830d61c89be78c581cb/src/main/clojure/cljs/compiler.cljc#L401-L407) code is instructive.

So, if `(var project.db/validation-function)` (or the reader equivalent `#'project.db/validation-function`) doesn't exist anywhere in your source code (or indirectly via the use of something like `ns-publics`) this data won't be available at runtime.

The omission of var reification is a good thing when optimizing for code size. If you enable the [:repl-verbose](https://clojurescript.org/reference/repl-options#repl-verbose) REPL option, you will see that the expression `(var project.db/validation-function)` emits a significant amount of JavaScript code.

When working with `def`s at the REPL, the compiler carries sufficient analysis metadata, and things are done—like having evaluations of `def` forms return the var rather than the value—in the name of constructing an illusion that you are working with reified Clojure vars. But this illusion intentionally evaporates when producing code for production delivery, preserving only essential runtime behavior.

Comment: Thank you, very clear! Interestingly the dynamic call `(meta ((ns-publics 'project.db) (symbol (name (pred))))` works. I'll try to work out why using what you've explained.

Comment: @JeremyField Yes, using `ns-publics` builds a static map from symbols to vars for a given namespace at compile time. So this approach effectively works (but only for vars in the given namespace), at the cost of dumping all vars in that namespace into the compiled code. In other words, it is a tradeoff with limitations.

Answer (score 0):

edit: sorry I didn't see that `var` didn't work for you. Still working on it...

You need to surround the symbol `project.db/validation-function` with [var](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/var). This will resolve the symbol to a var.

So `what-goes-here?` should be

```
(defn what-goes-here? [pred]
  (var pred))
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `var` isn't working. It's actually giving "Unable to resolve var: pred in this context" now, not the gensym. Also interestingly I was able to get an arity error by trying to run `(pred)`. It seemed to return `nil` when called correctly though, when it should have returned `true`... Sorry I'm new to lisp.

Comment: I suppose you could create a function that checks if pred is equal to `project.db/validation-function`, and then return the var. `(if (= pred 'project.db/validation-function) #'project.db/validation-function)`. You could then get the meta data off that. You would have to do this for every `var` in the namespace. You could do it dynamically with `(keys (ns-publics project.db)`.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly they compare `=` but not `identical?`.